# Why is my command prompt being returned prematurely on a Ctrl+C?

Tags: go

I've got a program where I spawn a goroutine to monitor for a SIGINT so I can do some cleanup work before exiting the program. However I've noticed that the cmd prompt for the terminal is returned immediately after the Ctrl+C which means that a bunch of the output spills over. Here's the code and an example of what I'm seeing:

```golang
sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, os.Interrupt)
//spawn a thread to wait on the sigterm op
go func() {
    <-sigs
    fmt.Println("Received a signal interrupt, stopping container")
    stopContainer(containerName)
    os.Exit(0)
}()
runtime.Gosched()
//rest of program that prints logs from a running docker container
```

The output looks like this

```
^CReceived a signal interrupt, stopping container
Received a signal interrupt, stopping container

mbp:myDir myName$ Stopping the 'javaTest-tools' container...
Stopping the 'javaTest-tools' container...

Build time: 3m31.275495945s
Done.
```

You can see that the 3rd line of output that begins with `mpb:myDir myName$` is the cmd line prompt being returned and then stdout being printed afterwards. I'm a little baffled by why the cmd line acts like the program ends earlier than it does.

Comment: is `stopContainer(...)` a blocking call?

Comment: @zerkms yes, in other words, that go-thread i spawn will wait for `stopContainer()` to finish before executing `os.Exit(0)`

Comment: But the main thread is not being blocked if that's what you mean. @zerkms also the "Received a signal interrupt, stopping container..." string is printing twice, I also found that odd

Comment: Any chance you receive more than one signal? What if you increase channel buffer?

Comment: @zerkms disregard the last comment, it's not printing output twice, but the output is for sure spilling over the command prompt. It's pretty confusing to me how the command prompt is returning before the program stops printing output to stdout.

Comment: What shell do you use? Any additional shell-related managers like screen or tmux?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138578/discussion-between-sreya-and-zerkms).